# Test influences real database

Tags: django

**Django 1.9.7**
**PostgreSQL 9.5.3**

Could you help me understand what happens. Tests influence my real database. Though in the console it announces "Creating test database for alias 'default'".

When I run tests, then run server and go to http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/, I can see two users: 1) michael, and 2) fe64d759-419c-41d7-b266-acfeb0 with email lennon@thebeatles.com.

Well, the last one is definitely created during the test. I can delete it and doublecheck: such users are definitely created by the test.

There is another problem here: Key (created_by_id)=(14) is not present in table "auth_user". I don't know whether it is connected to title problem. 
Maybe it isn't but I'll try to cope with that after my real database is separated and safe.

Anyway the test influences the real database. Could you help me here?

**/pharchive/pharchive/settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'michael',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

**/pharchive/masterdocument/tests.py**

```
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
today = datetime.datetime.today()

def create_user(name = None):
        name = (name or str(uuid.uuid4())[:30])    
        user = User.objects.create_user(name, 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')    
        return user  

class MasterDocumentTest(TransactionTestCase):    


    user = create_user()

    def create_master_document(self, title=None,
                           dated_from=today,
                           dated_through=today,
                           created_by=user,
                           creation_date=today):

        title = title or "Some title"

        md = MasterDocument.objects.create(title = title,
                                           dated_from = dated_from,
                                           dated_through = dated_through,
                                           created_by = created_by,
                                           creation_date = creation_date)
        return md

    def test_0_create_master_document(self):
        self.create_master_document()

        number_of_mds = MasterDocument.objects.all().count()
        self.assertEqual(number_of_mds, 1)
```

**Traceback**

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
ERROR: test_0_create_master_document (masterdocument.tests.MasterDocumentTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
psycopg2.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "masterdocument_masterdocument" violates foreign key constraint "masterdocument_masterdoc_created_by_id_5cb1a3d5_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (created_by_id)=(14) is not present in table "auth_user".


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/pharchive/pharchive/masterdocument/tests.py", line 41, in test_0_create_master_document
    self.create_master_document()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/pharchive/pharchive/masterdocument/tests.py", line 37, in create_master_document
    creation_date = creation_date)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 223, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "masterdocument_masterdocument" violates foreign key constraint "masterdocument_masterdoc_created_by_id_5cb1a3d5_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (created_by_id)=(14) is not present in table "auth_user".


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.518s

FAILED (errors=1)
Finished "/home/michael/workspace/pharchive/pharchive/manage.py test" execution.
```

Comment: try adding `user = create_user()`  inside `def create_master_document` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `user = create_user()` inside `def create_master_document`.

or

```
self.user = create_user()
def create_master_document(created_by = self.user)
```